# How to execute "left outer join" in SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I need to execute this query::

```
select field11, field12
from Table_1 t1
left outer join Table_2 t2 ON t2.tbl1_id = t1.tbl1_id
where t2.tbl2_id is null
```

I had these classes in python:

```
class Table1(Base):
   ....

class Table2(Base):
   table_id =  Column(
        Integer,
        ForeignKey('Table1.id', ondelete='CASCADE'),
    )
    ....
```

How do I get to the above from the below?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

```
q = session.query(Table1.field1, Table1.field2)\
    .outerjoin(Table2)\ # use in case you have relationship defined
    # .outerjoin(Table2, Table1.id == Table2.table_id)\ # use if you do not have relationship defined
    .filter(Table2.tbl2_id == None)
```

should do it, assuming that `field1` and `field2` are from `Table1`, and that you define a relationship:

```
class Table2(Base):
    # ...
    table1 = relationship(Table1, backref="table2s")
```

Comment: Is there a way you could do this if Table1 and Table2 are the same tables?

Comment: Sure you can. Read [Using Aliases](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html#using-aliases) section of the documentation.

Answer (score 20):

You can also do that using SQLAlchemy Core only:

```
session.execute(
    select(['field11', 'field12'])
    .select_from(
        Table1.outerjoin(Table2, Table1.tbl1_id == Table2.tbl1_id))
    .where(Table2.tbl2_id.is_(None))
)
```

PS `.outerjoin(table, condition)` is equivalent to `.join(table, condition, isouter=True)`.

Comment: Also `Table1.outerjoin(Table2, Table1.tbl1_id == Table2.tbl1_id)`.

Comment: Why do you need the where clause here? Doesn't that limit you to just those records where Table2 has a null in ID? If you don't include the where clause do you end up with a full outer join?

Comment: See the question. @Roosh wanted to filter the field out. For full outer join you should add full=True to the call.