# SQLAlchemy filter query results based on other table's field

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have got a not very common join and filter problem.

Here are my models;

```py
class Order(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    order_id = Column(String(19), nullable=False)
    ... (other fields)

class Discard(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    order_id = Column(String(19), nullable=False)
```

I want to query all and full instances of `Order` but just exclude those that have a match in `Discard.order_id` based on `Order.order_id` field. As you can see there is no relationship between `order_id` fields.

I've tried outer left join, `notin_` but ended up with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26144444/4132845) I've achieved desired results.

Here is my code;

```py
orders = (
    session.query(Order)
    .outerjoin(Discard, Order.order_id == Discard.order_id)
    .filter(Discard.order_id == None)  # noqa: E711
    .all()
)
```

I was paying too much attention to flake8 wrong syntax message at `Discard.order_id == None` and was using `Discard.order_id is None`. It appeared out they were rendered differently by sqlalchemy.